# Applications stop responding 5 minutes after starting desktop session on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, graphics

I am a new Ubuntu user and I moved to Ubuntu 16.04 a week ago.

When I turn on my PC I can use it normally for about 5 minutes. After that, it is impossible for me to open any app, and the ones already open just don't respond, although I can still navigate on my PC.

When I go to the process manager, I can see all my apps that are not responding but I can't kill them.

Also when I click on shutdown button (or reboot), my PC freezes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you running out of memory? do you have swap enabled?

Comment: No I am not, I have 16gb of memory and a 500mb swap partition.

Comment: When the system starts to freeze, could you please run `{ free -h; ps aux; } | curl -F 'clbin=<-' https://clbin.com` and then edit your question to include the returned link? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I couldn't get a link from your command line. Told me "curl : couldn't resolve host". Though I figure out that my problem came from graphic pilotes. So I installed new ones and every thing work fine now. I thank you for your time.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To solve my problem, I had to install new nvidia drivers. The applications stop freezing and I can shut down normally.